# Dealing with Zend Auth Data when using zend modules

Tags: zend-framework, zend-auth, zend-session, zend-session-namespace

I am working on zend module based structure for my project. As `Zend_Auth` class' default session storage is `Zend_Auth`. I changed according to module being called. Say for admin I use auth namespace `Admin_Auth` and for default module i use namespace name `Default_Auth`.

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$auth->setStorage(new Zend_Auth_Storage_Session('Admin_Auth'));
```

I am doing this because, if I do `Zend_Session::destroy()` it will destroy complete session even for Default Module. and so using namespace and so at logout `Zend_Session::namespaceUnset('Admin_Auth');`

each time in different controller I have to use

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$auth->setStorage(new Zend_Auth_Storage_Session('Admin_Auth'));
```

just to point corresponding session data.

I am considering to move it in module's `Bootstrap.php` like

```
protected function _initAuth(){

    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $auth->setStorage(new Zend_Auth_Storage_Session('Admin_Auth'));

    return $auth;
}
```

First, is that proper way?
Second, If it is then how can I access the return value `$auth` of `_initAuth()` in each controller? Please

Comment: This won't work, because module bootstraps are run on every request, so each module will replace the storage for the previous one. Why do you need different auth data for each module?

Comment: @TimFountain because when I set `$authStorage->write($identity);` these data become available for default module to. so I dont want default module to have those data

Comment: Okay, but why? If it's an attempt to secure the session data, it's just being written to `$_SESSION`, so regardless of the namespace you use it will always be available to all PHP scripts running on your domain.

Comment: You could use a plugin with a `preDispatch()` hook that tests for the `moduleName` and sets storage as required. http://devzone.zend.com/1224/front-controller-plugins-in-zend-framework/